# Unity Browser inside UI Panel

Tags: unity, html, browser

What is the best option if I want to show a remote webpage inside a UI Panel in Unity ?

I want to target android and iOs platform.

I had uniWebView in mind but that thing is more like an overlay I guess, or can it be kept in bound of the panel (the canvas which holds the panel is using world co-ordinate) ?

Comment: Why don't you just email the authors and ask them? I'm pretty certain uniWebView will do what you want...